# Using Windows shortcut with 'cmd /c start' not the same as from console

Tags: windows, start-menu, anaconda

I'm using this method to launch Anaconda Prompt 32-bit version *"open a regular command prompt, figure out where miniconda got installed, cd to the miniconda\Scripts directory and type "activate".* [Rsignell](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/352#issuecomment-157761578) I'd like to be able to activate this from Cortana/Start Menu, because I'm using both 32 and 64-bit versions.

Following this [workaround](https://winaero.com/blog/pin-a-batch-file-to-the-start-menu-or-taskbar-in-windows-10/) I added a **shortcut**:

```
cmd /c start "C:\path\to\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate"
```

with the name "Anaconda Prompt (32)". This icon has the right-click contextual **Pin to Start** option and Cortana can find this 32-bit shortcut.

However, the console that's launched is not an active conda environment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32 >` and should show up as `(conda) C:\WINDOWS\system32 >`. The same line used in a console will activate conda. Any suggestions to fix this solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The console that's launched is not an active conda environment

You are using the `start` command incorrectly and it is not executing `C:\path\to\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate`.

The first parameter for `start` is the title bar text.

Try using:

```
cmd /c start "" "C:\path\to\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate"
```

Usage:

```
Syntax
      START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]

Key:
   title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
   path        Starting directory.
   command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
   parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
```

...

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or
>   just a pair of empty quotes "" According to the Microsoft
>   documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other
>   options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Source [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)

Comment: Wow! Great answer. That fixed it, but why does it work in the console?

Comment: @xtian Because from the console the sequence of commands you type don't have anything to do with `start`.

Comment: @DavidPostill Do tell - why does `cmd /c start "C:\some\path"` not have anything to do with `start`?

Comment: @user20574 Ah. I misunderstood. I don't know why it works in the console, other than what it says in the last part of the answer.